# How to fetch data using predicate with the ALL ... IN format string

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-data, nspredicate

So I have an core data entity 'transaction' with an attribute 'tags' which related to another entity 'tag'. The relationship type between the two entities is many to many. Which means a transaction can have many tags and a tag can have many transactions.

Now, I've created a method that will fetch transaction entries based on specific tags. The method looks similar to below:

```
func transactions(withTags tags: [Tag] = [], matchCriteria: String = "ANY") {...}
```

So in the function, I have used a predicate like the below:

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%@ <= date) AND (date < %@) AND (\(matchCriteria) tags IN %@)", argumentArray: [startDate, endDate, tags])
```

So the key element in the predicate is the "ANY tags IN %@", which just basically searches for the given tag(s) and if any of those tags are found in the entry, then there would be a match. This predicate works perfectly for that purpose.

But now, what I want to do is to have a similar predicate but, I would like it to return a match only when ALL of the given tags are found. For example, if I have 2 tags e.g. 'planned' and 'paid'. Then only entries with both tags should be returned.

So, based on the Apple documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795, it appears there's an "ALL" operator. So I tried creating a predicate similar to the below:

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%@ <= date) AND (date < %@) AND (ALL tags IN %@)", argumentArray: [startDate, endDate, tags])
```

Just substituted ANY with ALL. But it doesn't seem to work and it crashes my app. The error I get is "Thread 1: Exception: "Unsupported predicate...". This is where I'm stuck, and hope that you guys can point me towards the right direction.

What should the correct predicate be for me to satisfy the above requirements?

Answer (score 0):

First just a note that, even if it didn't crash, your predicate ("ALL tags in %@", tags) wouldn't do quite what you want.  It would ensure that a transaction is included in the results only if all its tags are in the list.  But if it had only one tag, that matched only one from your list, it would still be included.  What you need is the reverse ("ALL %@ IN tags").  But that will cause the same crash.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to prepare a compound predicate, taking each tag from your list in turn, eg:

```
"(ANY tags == 'planned') AND (ANY tags == 'paid')"
```

You can construct this fairly quickly for your `tags` array:

```
let datePredicateArray = [NSPredicate(format: "(%@ <= date) AND (date < %@)", argumentArray: [startDate, endDate])]
let tagPredicateArray = tags.map {NSPredicate(format:"ANY tags == %@", $0)}
let allPredicates = datePredicateArray + tagPredicateArray
let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: allPredicates)
```

Comment: Waw, that started to become really confusing there :-D but it made sense. And I think that worked! I'll do additional case tests and see if it holds up. Thanks!